# Sonarlint and other tools for eclipse to mimic sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarlint

On my local machine for my project trying to see the code quality related issues that sonarqube shows.

Using eclipse IDE.
Installed sonarlint plugin and I am able to see most of the issues that I see in the sonarqube for my project.
But, don’t see issues related to duplicate code etc

From what I see on internet sonarqube uses other third party tools like PMD, checksyle, findbugs to show other issues apart from what sonarlint shows.

Who usually provide the xml rulesets for PMD, Checkstyle etc in the company? Is it the sonar team or the architecture team? or the project team leads create one and provide it to the team.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, SonarLint runs analyses file by file,
so it cannot display errors involving multiple files, such as:

- Duplications
- Test coverage
- Package-level issues (`package-info.java` is missing, etc)

Furthermore, it only shows issues from SonarSource analyzers,
third party analyzers such as PMD and checkstyle are excluded.

Finally, it will show the same issues as you see in SonarQube in connected mode.
Otherwise, in standalone mode,
it uses the default quality profile (= set of rules),
as defined by its embedded analyzers,
which may slightly vary depending on their version.

The differences that you see between SonarLint and SonarQube will come down to one or more of the reasons as explained above.

> Who usually provide the xml rulesets for PMD, Checkstyle etc in the company? Is it the sonar team or the architecture team? or the project team leads create one and provide it to the team.

That depends on the company, and any answer to this would be subjective.

Comment: Thanks, for responding